# Time Zone difference between Time.now and 1.day.ago

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

My app `time_zone` is set to `UTC`(default, I didn't change it in config/application.rb).

This is what I see in rails console

```
1.9.3p194 :004 > Time.now
 => 2014-03-20 14:45:23 -0500 
1.9.3p194 :005 > 1.day.ago
 => Wed, 19 Mar 2014 19:45:48 UTC +00:00
```

Why do I get the time in central when I do `Time.now`? It should return time in UTC like `1.day.ago`

Answer (score 3):

`Time.now` uses the locale of the machine it is running on.  For consistency, you can do `Time.now.utc` to force UTC:

```
1.9.3-p484 :001 > Time.now
2014-03-20 16:14:23 -0400
1.9.3-p484 :002 > Time.now.utc
2014-03-20 20:14:26 UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Time.zone.now` - it will take into account your application's time zone:

project with default TZ:

```
2.0.0-p353 :001 > Time.now
 => 2014-04-01 23:12:06 +0300 
2.0.0-p353 :002 > Time.zone.now
 => Tue, 01 Apr 2014 20:12:11 UTC +00:00 
2.0.0-p353 :003 >
```

project with custom TZ:

```
2.1.0 :001 > Time.now
 => 2014-04-01 23:14:23 +0300 
2.1.0 :002 > Time.zone.now
 => Tue, 01 Apr 2014 22:14:27 CEST +02:00 
2.1.0 :003 >
```

Here you'll find more useful info about working with timezones (especially take a look at DOs and DONTs section):

http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails